# How to convert Ajax (Jquery) into fetch async

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I wrote this code and it's works perfect for me.
But when i try to convert it to fetch, dosen't work because return a promise.
I don't know how to use it as a async false on fetch.

```
            'getProjectConstants': function(constArray)
            {
                var result='';
                $.ajax({
                type:       "GET",
                url:        `${constProjectBaseUrl}/ajax/getProjectConstants/${constArray}`,
                async:      false,
                dataType:   "json",
                success: function(data) {
                result = data
            }
        });
        return result
```

I tried to do like this, but dosen't work

```
        fetch(`${constProjectBaseUrl}/ajax/getProjectConstants/${constArray}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
             // console.log(response)
             return response
        }) // end of .then((response) => {
        .catch(error => {
             console.log("[ajax.getProjectConstants] Error => " + error);
        }); // end of .catch(error => {
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088454/7644018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
async function getProjectConstants(){
    const json = await (await fetch(`${constProjectBaseUrl}/ajax/getProjectConstants/${constArray}`)).json();
    return json;
}
ajax.getProjectConstants(['PROJECT_PASSWORD_MINIMUM', 'OWNER_NAME', 'DB_TBL_TIME_ZONE']).then((constant) => {
    console.log(constant.OWNER_NAME)
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hi @Tanay...
Unfortunately it doesn't work, first it returns null and then the result, as if async wasn't working

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling the networkRequest function?

Comment: Hi, sure, thanks for quickly reply

 constant = ajax.getProjectConstants(['PROJECT_PASSWORD_MINIMUM', 'OWNER_NAME', 'DB_TBL_TIME_ZONE']);
 console.log(constant.OWNER_NAME)

Comment: You need to use then and catch here, or use async/await since the object returned is promise

Comment: Could you please help me litte bit more.
I'm begginer on JS... my strong skills is PhP

I dont know how to do what you said on JS :(

Comment: Ok, no problem @Gustavo Filgueiras